# MemoryCache.Set return removed cache item

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I am using the .NET 4.0 [`MemoryCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780634%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class, and I want to add or replace an existing item in the cache in a thread-safe manner, but I also want to know whether I have replaced an existing item or added a new one.

From what I can tell, the [`Set`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee395903%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method is intended for the purpose of atomically replacing an item in the cache if it exists, whereas the [`AddOrGetExisting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee395901%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method will atomically get me the existing item without replacing it.

However, the Set method doesn't return the item that was replaced, it just replaces it. It is possible to hook up a removed event to the [`CacheItemPolicy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for items, but hard to match that up with the new item that replaced it.

I can approximate it with the following method, but it seems a bit heavy (because of asking the cache to essentially add an item twice) and I wanted to ask if someone knows an easier way to do it.

```
public object SetAndGetExisting(string key, object value, CacheItemPolicy policy, string regionName = null)
{
    lock (_cacheLock)
    {
        var existing = _cache.AddOrGetExisting(key, value, policy, regionName);

        if (existing != null)
        {
            _cache.Set(key, value, policy, regionName);
            return existing;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see why you are calling set.  If it is null, it didn't exist and it was already added.  You should just return the results of the AddOrGetExisting method.  You are over-thinking it.

Comment: Because if there is an existing item, it won't add my new item. AddOrGetExisting will only add the new item if an item doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Did you try to use the double-checked idiom for this case? You can read more on this wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking

Comment: Can you give a little more background information on what you are trying to accomplish?  It seems odds to set a new value, and even after setting the new data, you return the old data.

Comment: Thanks, I know double-checked locking. I don't think it applies in this case, because the method that "checks" also adds, although I guess I could do it by using the Get method instead of AddOrGetExisting. Anyway, while I suppose the synchronisation above can be improved in a number of ways, the question is really whether it's possible to do the above without the explicit locking.

Comment: @Justin - I am trying to add cache events, and will not necessarily be returning the old item. What I am really looking for, is a way to tell (easily) whether an item has just been added, or whether it has been updated (i.e. replaced a previous entry).

Comment: Is it really so strange to want to do this? Most caching technologies I have used in the past (e.g. Coherence) has the ability to return the replaced item when adding elements to the cache.

Comment: To me, the usefulness is minimal unless you are logging it for some reason.  I can't think of a situation, off the top of my head, where knowing if the item was added or updated would be useful outside of logging.  It seems you have an existing class, so you can easily add and event and call it: `public EventHandler<CacheChangeEventArgs> AddedCacheItem; public EventHandler<CacheChangeEventArgs> UpdatedCacheItem;` and call them depending on which situation occured.  The easiest way is with the AddOrGetExisting method to determine what action was performed.

Comment: @Justin - okay, thanks. I will do that for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking about it, in your example, you are updating it regardless, so `AddOrGetExisting` isn't the best, as you mentioned, you are setting it later anyway.  Below it a simple implementation that I **think** fits what you are asking for.  If I am wrong, please let me know!

```
public class MemoryCacheWithEvents
{
    private static MemoryCache _cache = new MemoryCache("myCache");
    private static object _syncLock = new object();

    public EventHandler<CacheChangeEventArgs> AddingCacheItem;
    public EventHandler<CacheChangeEventArgs> UpdatingCacheItem;


    public object GetAndSetExisting(string key, object value, CacheItemPolicy policy, string regionName = null)
    {
        lock (_syncLock)
        {
            var cacheItem = new CacheItem(key, value, regionName);

            var existing = _cache.GetCacheItem(key, null);

            if (existing == null)
            {
                OnAddingCacheItem(new CacheChangeEventArgs(null, cacheItem));
            }
            else
            {
                OnUpdatingCacheItem(new CacheChangeEventArgs(existing, cacheItem));   
            }

            _cache.Set(cacheItem, policy);

            return existing;
        }
    }

    public virtual void OnAddingCacheItem(CacheChangeEventArgs eventArgs){
        var handler = AddingCacheItem;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, eventArgs);
        }
    }

    public virtual void OnUpdatingCacheItem(CacheChangeEventArgs eventArgs){
        var handler = UpdatingCacheItem;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, eventArgs);
        }
    }
}

public class CacheChangeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public object OldCacheItem { get; set; }
    public object NewCacheItem { get; set; }

    public CacheChangeEventArgs(object oldCacheItem, object newCacheItem)
    {
        this.OldCacheItem = oldCacheItem;
        this.NewCacheItem = newCacheItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, I've been thinking of this optimisation myself, thanks a lot. I'll mark it as the answer. I'm using Rx (Reactive Extensions) for the notifications though, events are so old-school ;-)

Comment: It's a pity about the extra locking though, but I don't think there's a way around it.